# how do i get the current date in groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I'm trying to write some jmeter JSR223 preprocessor groovy to create some random variables. I'll be honest I have no idea what I'm doing!

I've managed to get out some random strings for names, but I have a few issues here:

1. I can't get a date out of the code (idea is to get a random date between 2 values and use that, but firstly I'm trying just to get today's date);
2. I want the middle name to be a bit random - so some test will have them some wont, and if the string has a c in in, i want to change it to a -add

Here is my code:

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Date; 

class ApplicantDetailsPage{

    var vars = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables();
    String applicantOneMiddleName = "";

    Date date = new Date();
    
    
    void main(){

        // Set the number of applicants
        ${__Random(1,2,noOfApplicants)};
        vars.put("noOfApplicants", noOfApplicants);

        // set applicant one detials
        ${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz, applicantOneFirstName)}
        vars.put("applicantOneFirstName", applicantOneFirstName);

        ${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz, firstApplicantLastName)}
        firstApplicantLastName = firstApplicantLastName.contains("c") ? firstApplicantLastName.replace("c", "c-add") : firstApplicantLastName;
        vars.put("firstApplicantLastName", firstApplicantLastName);

        ${__Random(0,1,isApplicantOneMiddleName)};
        vars.put("isApplicantOneMiddleName", isApplicantOneMiddleName);

        if(vars.get("isApplicantOneMiddleName").contains(1)){
            ${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz, applicantOneMiddleName)}
            vars.put("applicantOneMiddleNametApplicantLastName", applicantOneMiddleName);
        }


        def datePart = date.format("dd/MM/yyyy");
        vars.put("currentDate", datePart);
        
    }   

}

log.info ('********** noOfApplicants ' + vars.get("noOfApplicants")+ ' ***********')
log.info ('********** applicantOneFirstName ' + vars.get("applicantOneFirstName")+ ' ***********')
log.info ('********** firstApplicantLastName ' + vars.get("firstApplicantLastName")+ ' ***********')
log.info ('********** isApplicantOneMiddleName ' + vars.get("isApplicantOneMiddleName")+ ' ***********')
log.info ('********** applicantOneMiddleName ' + vars.get("applicantOneMiddleName")+ ' ***********')
log.info ('********** currentDate ' + vars.get("currentDate")+ ' ***********')
```

but the date field always comes back as null, and the if statements in the code don't seem to do anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It would be something like:

```
def now = new Date()
```

if you want some specific [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
def now = new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

if you want a random date:

```
(new Date()..new Date(2050-1900,5,1)).toList().sort{Math.random()}[0]
```

Also don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables into Groovy scripts, either use "Parameters" section or go for code-based equivalents like [RandomStringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html)

More information:

- [JSR223 Sampler Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
- [Groovy Goodness: Working with Dates](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-working-with-dates.html)